# how JSON response can be use to oracle as relational data in oracle 10G

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, plsql

JSON input

```
response := {"TECHS":[{"Technology":"NGN","Line_capacity":"20 Mbps","IPTV_capable":"TRUE"}],"TECH_CHANGE_REQ":"FALSE","RESERVATION_REQ":"TRUE","PREMIER_STATUS":"false","ERROR_CODE":"0000","ERROR_MESSAGE":null}
```

my query so far:

```
select substr(response,instr(response,'Technology'),instr(response,'Line_capacity":')-instr(response,'Technology')),
substr(response,instr(response,'Line_capacity'),instr(response,'IPTV_capable":')-instr(response,'Line_capacity')),
substr(response,instr(response,'IPTV_capable'),instr(response,'}]')-instr(response,'Line_capacity'))
--instr(response,'Technology'),instr(response,'Line_capacity') 
from dual
;
```

Output im looking for:

[image]

Comment: im using oracle 10G, i need to easy manipulate json data in oracle db

Answer (score 0):

If lentgh of text is below 32767 bytes use VARCHAR2.

Otherwise use CLOB.